# Redirect to Same method in Same Controller in Symfony (Pagination links)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Well i have this Method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/articles/{category}/{id}/true/{page}", defaults={"page"=1}, name="articleAjax")
 */
public function getArticlesAjax($category, $id, $page)
{
}
```

Inside i want to create pagination link, like this:

```
    $html .= '<ul>';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
        $html .= '<li><a href="">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
```

But now, how to set href to same method and pass variables. Then in view file, just to render this variable `$html` Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use a template engine such Twig and leave the HTML code in the view. Writting HTML in the controller is against separation of concerns

Comment: @Cid I tried, but all comments, subcomments and forms are with AJAX and i cannot do it without return HTML from controller. You can check whole implementation here [GitHub](https://github.com/MorganFreeFarm/Symfony-Comments-Subcomments-AJAX)

Comment: Of course you can. Nothing stops you from building some HTML in javascript the way you did it in php, using the datas received with the ajax call

Comment: By the way, I use [knp paginator](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle) to build pagination and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Cid, Okay i will move whole HTML in js file, if ajax is success :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate a url of a controller inside a controller use `$this->generateUrl()` in your exmaple you could do something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
    $route = $this->generateUrl('articleAjax', [
        'category' => $category,
        'id' => $id,
        'page' => $i,
    ]);

    $html .= '<li><a href="'. $route. '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}
```

But I would recomment to this in your twig template and there use the `{{ path() }}` function.